# Android-Maven Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojoto when install

Tags: android, maven, maven-2, development-environment, android-maven-plugin

I am setting up a new Android-Maven development using the new Android ADT Bundle and Android-Mavem Deployer.

The `$ANDROID_HOME` is `/Users/allanhahaha/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130917/sdk`

When I ran `mvn clean install -X` in `maven-android-sdk-deployer-master` folder, I got these errors:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.966s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Oct 12 20:34:27 PDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2:read-project-properties (default) on project android-3: Properties file not found: /Users/allanhahaha/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130917/sdk/platforms/android-3/source.properties -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :android-3
```

and here are some extra error messages:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2:read-project-properties (default) on project android-3: Properties file not found: /Users/allanhahaha/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130917/sdk/platforms/android-3/source.properties
```

It looks pretty strange to me since I don't even have the `android-3` folder:

```
ALLAN-MacBook-Pro:platforms allanhahaha$ pwd
/Users/allanhahaha/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130917/sdk/platforms
ALLAN-MacBook-Pro:platforms allanhahaha$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  11 allanhahaha  staff  374 Oct 12 18:15 android-10
drwxr-xr-x  12 allanhahaha  staff  408 Oct 12 18:14 android-11
drwxr-xr-x  12 allanhahaha  staff  408 Oct 12 18:13 android-12
drwxr-xr-x  12 allanhahaha  staff  408 Oct 12 18:12 android-13
drwxr-xr-x  10 allanhahaha  staff  340 Oct 12 18:10 android-14
drwxr-xr-x  10 allanhahaha  staff  340 Oct 12 18:10 android-15
drwxr-xr-x  11 allanhahaha  staff  374 Oct 12 18:10 android-16
drwxr-xr-x  11 allanhahaha  staff  374 Oct 12 18:09 android-17
drwxrwx---@ 11 allanhahaha  staff  374 Sep 10 11:56 android-18
drwxr-xr-x  11 allanhahaha  staff  374 Oct 12 18:16 android-8
```

And here is part of my POM.xml configuration:

```
<build>
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
      <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <sdk>
          <platform>${android.sdk.platform}</platform>
        </sdk>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
<extensions>
  <extension>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
  </extension>
</extensions>
```

I am new to maven so have no idea about what is going on with this error message. Please help take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know why this happens, but it seems like open up the Android SDK Manager and re-install the package that contains the error could help (in my case install the `Android 1.5(API 3)` including both the SDK Platform and the Google APIs), and run again the mvn installer.

Comment: Why was this answer down voted? Seems to me the correct answer. The Android Maven Deployer README suggests this exact workaround.

Answer (score 1):

ANDROID_HOME has to point to your Android SDK and not the ADT.

E.g. I use

```
export $ANDROID_HOME=/opt/tools/android-sdk-mac_86
```